# Font Awesome Icons fa-undo-circle

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

Im looking for a good font awesome icon I could use as a "Reset" button for my application.

Im currently using fa-undo which looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that I need it to have a circle around it as the other buttons in my system do ( these are standard in font awesome icons, nothing has been modified except the color )

An example of what i need (with the undo image):

[image]

Ive been reading through the list [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) for nearly an hour but cant think of a possible alternative. Any thoughts?

Comment: Set color:white; for icon, the background blue, with border-radius:50%. It is that what you need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FA has some utility classes, one of which is `fa-stack`. You can stack `fa-circle` underneath `fa-undo`.

```css
.fa-circle {
  color: #008db8;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-undo fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Perfect Ben, thank you. I wasnt aware there was a stack feature available.